# Loading NuGet packages online and pre-install them

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, project-template

I know that I can [pre-install](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates) NuGet packages in my project templates.
But I wasn't able to find out whether it is possible to load these packages online instead of having to store them somewhere in the project template.

If this is possible please give me a hint where I can find an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older article, but answers the question:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/07/08/project-templates-and-preinstalled-nuget-packages.aspx

> A frequent question is why not support downloading the nupkg files directly from http://nuget.org. We decided not to support such an option because users expect project templates to instantiate quickly and downloading files from the internet would slow things down. Also, it would not work on a plane or in other situations where a connection is not available.

Comment: Yeah, the option should be there for, and then let the developers decide which method to use.